# RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9 in ubuntu

Tags: numpy, theano

I just installed theano, but

```
import numpy
print numpy.version
```

here is the output

```
Theano version 0.7.0.dev-30cc6380863b08a3a90ecbe083ddfb629a56161d
theano is installed in /home/sizhexi/theano/Theano/theano
NumPy version 1.8.2
NumPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) [GCC 4.8.2]
nose version 1.3.1
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  numpy failed to initialize
Aborted (core dumped)
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Package management in python is sometimes tricky. To avoid these issues, I recommend using Anaconda which is a good python package and environment manager ([download here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), and [30 minutes guide](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html)).

Follow the official instructions to install Anaconda and chose the default values that will add Anaconda to your $PATH and make Anaconda your default python interpreter. Then open your terminal and use the following commands :

- `conda install pip six nose numpy scipy`
- `pip install theano`

Then try running your script using anaconda.